# Map database params field values to custom names

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, database, error-handling

I am trying to handle an array of errors on the front end side and display them on the page. I am getting the fields that user has entered from the backend and trying to map them out. However, backend params are being returned in camelcase. Please see below:

[image]

I want to render:
The input field(s) for email, favorite sport, gpa score are unacceptable

But I am seeing

The input field(s) for email, favoriteSport, gpaScore are unacceptable

Is there any way I can map the name of the params to a custom name?

Here is my code:

```
Array.isArray(errors) ? `The input fields for ${errors.map(item => item.param)} are unacceptable`
```

Any way i could map the param names to my own liking?

Comment: what is the logic you are using to to set the params property on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapper = (item) => {
  return {
   gpaScore: 'GPA Score',
   favoriteSport: 'Favorite Sport',
  }[item.param] || 'Unknown property'
} 

return `The input fields for ${errors.map(item => mapper(item)).join(', ')} are unacceptable`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you could use something like [react-intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/) to format messages but in general, you'd need something that turns programmatic keys into user-friendly messages

```js
const t = {
  email: "email",
  favoriteSport: "favourite sport",
  gpaScore: "GPA score"
}

const fields = errors.map(({ param }) => t[param] ?? param)

const message = `The input fields for ${fields.join(", ")} are unacceptable`
```